# Erlang spawn simple process from erl .. no such process or port

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

When running this code in the Erlang console

```
Pid = spawn(fun() -> "foo" end),link(Pid),receive X -> X end.
```

I receive the following error.

````
** exception error: no such process or port
 in function  link/1
    called as link(<0.71.0>)```
````

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens because the process you spawn finishes very quickly: it only "returns" a string (and the return value goes nowhere, since it is the top-level function in the call stack of the new process), so it's very likely to finish before the emulator gets to the `link` call.

You can make it more likely to succeed by making the process sleep before exiting:

```
2> Pid = spawn(fun() -> timer:sleep(1000), "foo" end),link(Pid).
true
```

Note however that the `receive` expression in your example most likely won't receive anything, since the spawned process doesn't send any message, and the link won't generate any message either since the process exits normally, and the calling process most likely isn't trapping exits.  You may want to do something like:

```
Parent = self(),
spawn(fun() -> Parent ! "foo" end),
receive X -> X end.
```

That returns `"foo"`.